# Linux: How to replace a string of text containing quotes and commas in a file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I'm not the greatest with awk, perl, or sed, and I can't figure out how to replace a string of text in a file.

The string is somewhat unusual. Actually, there are 2 of them I need to replace in 1 file automatically.

The file contains a single line of text, very long, in JSON format. Per-line replacements won't work.

Here is the text I need to replace. From:

```
"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"libraries","objectsLocation":"objects",
```

to

```
"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"pack/libraries","objectsLocation":"pack/objects",
```

As you can see there are quotes in the text and slashes I need to enter, as well as commas and multiple occurences of libraries and objects, making my current knowledge of sed, awk, and perl useless.

How can I add the 'pack/' prefix to the text 'libraries' and 'objects'?

Comment: It looks like a JSON objects with the `{` and `}` missing.

Comment: Can you give a fuller example of your JSON - the answer would most likely be 'use a JSON parser'.

Comment: simbabque; this is a small sample of the original file, the whole file is 160k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add the 'pack/' prefix to the text 'libraries' and 'objects'?

How about a simple `sed` command:

```
echo '"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"libraries","objectsLocation":"objects",' > file

sed 's~"\(libraries\|objects\)"~"pack/\1"~g' file
```

**Output:**

```
"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"pack/libraries","objectsLocation":"pack/objects",
```

---

To run over ssh:

```
ssh ip<<'EOF'
sed -i 's~"libraries"~"pack/&"~; s~"objects"~"pack/&"~' file.json 
EOF
```

Comment: This didn't work, the output in `file` is the same as the original, after I use the `sed` line. If you can get it to work, how can I then incorporate the output to `file` into the original .json file?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `can't read s~"\(libraries\|objects\)"~"pack/\1"~g: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's perfect, except for one thing; there is one other occurrence of the word 'libraries' in the .json. Is there a way to make it only change the first occurrence of 'libraries' and 'objects?'

Comment: I got an error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 25: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: I got it! The problem was the `\1"`, replacing the 1 with 0 fixed it. sed apparently starts at 0 and goes up. Thanks!!!

Comment: Alright, another problem if you can help; the command works fine on the server, but I need to run the command over ssh. Here's the command I'm trying: `ssh [IP] 'sed -i '"'"'s~"libraries"~"pack/\0"~; s~"objects"~"pack/\0"~'"'"'[Directory]/text.json'`  However, the output in the file is: `"librariesLocation":"pack/"libraries"","objectsLocation":"pack/"objects"",` The words `objects` and `libraries` are surrounded by another pair of quotes. Any ideas, or is this a matter for another question?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I ran my script in terminal and it logged me into SSH, but as a user; I would have to type the sed command, if that makes sense.

Comment: ok at this point I suggest opening a new question as we are digressing a lot from the posted problem.

Comment: Here's the new issue if you have any answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619016/running-a-complicated-sed-command-over-ssh

Answer (score 3):

Please don't try and use regex for JSON. It's nasty. Use a JSON parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON; 

my $json_str = '{ "minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"libraries","objectsLocation":"objects" }';

my $json_ob = decode_json($json_str);

print "Before:", $json_ob -> {'librariesLocation'},"\n";

#pattern replace just the values we're interested in.
$json_ob -> {'librariesLocation'} =~ s,^,pack/,;
$json_ob -> {'objectsLocation'} =~ s,^,pack/,;

print "After: ", $json_ob -> {'librariesLocation'},"\n";

#print single line text blob
print encode_json($json_ob);
print "\n\n";

## or perhaps (formatted, multiline, whitespace):

print to_json($json_ob, { canonical => 1, pretty => 1 } );
```

This works with the rough sample - if you want a better one, give me more JSON and I'll redraft.

This outputs:

```
Before:libraries
After: pack/libraries
{"objectsLocation":"pack/objects","minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"pack/libraries"}

{
   "librariesLocation" : "pack/libraries",
   "minimumVersion" : 2,
   "objectsLocation" : "pack/objects"
}
```

Edit: To do this from a file:

```
local $/; 
open ( my $input, '<', 'source_filename_here' ) or die $!;
open ( my $output, '>', 'output_filename_here' ) or die $!;

my $json_ob = decode_json(<$input>);
#do the transforms

print {$output} encode_json($json_ob);
```

Or alternatively (reading from STDIN printing to STDOUT just like sed/grep etc.):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my @stuff_to_change = qw ( librariesLocation objectsLocation );

local $/;

#read from stdin or arg on commmand line. E.g.:
#myscript.pl somefile
#cat json_file | myscript.pl
my $json_ob = decode_json(<>);

#pattern replace just the values we're interested in.
for my $thing (@stuff_to_change) {
    $json_ob->{$thing} =~ s,^,pack/,;
}

#print single line text blob to STDOUT
print encode_json($json_ob);
```

Comment: I assume this is a script. How can I incorporate the output into the original file?

Comment: It is, I have edited to include an example of file IO. (There's more than one way of doing it, depending on precisely what you need though - you can make this work in a pipe if that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

sed --in-place will do the trick, with the correct escaping

```
$ echo '"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"libraries","objectsLocation":"objects",' > text.txt      
$ sed --in-place 's/"\(libraries\|objects\)"/"pack\/\1"/g' text.txt
$ cat text.txt 
  "minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"pack/libraries","objectsLocation":"pack/objects",
```

replace pattern `"libraries"` with `"pack/libraries"` (using grouping and reuse of matching pattern)

Comment: How can I incorporate the output in `text.txt` into the original .json?

Comment: replace text.txt with yourFile.json... This will modify the existing file, without creating a backup (as in "in place")

Comment: The original file is very long; I only included a snippet of the file. However, note that there are 2 occurrences of the word `libraries` in the file. I only need to prefix the first. The word `objects` only occurs once. I've looked into doing this with `sed` but I can't figure it out. I tried using this: `'0/s/"\(libraries\|objects\)"/"pack\/\1"/g'` with no success, I get an error saying 'Invalid usage of the line address 0"

Answer (score 0):

With proper JSON input, you could use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq '.librariesLocation |= "pack/"+., .objectsLocation |= "pack/"+.' <<EOF
{"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"libraries","objectsLocation":"objects"}
EOF
{
  "minimumVersion": 2,
  "librariesLocation": "pack/libraries",
  "objectsLocation": "objects"
}
{
  "minimumVersion": 2,
  "librariesLocation": "libraries",
  "objectsLocation": "pack/objects"
}
```

If your input is just a comma-separated list of key/value pairs, you *might* be able to use `jq` to turn it into a proper JSON object before filtering, but I don't know `jq` well enough yet to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/libraries",|objects",/, "pack/&")}1' file
minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"pack/libraries","objectsLocation":"pack/objects",
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.