# Problems running a complicated sed command over SSH

Tags: json, linux, bash, ssh, sed

I've read multiple other answers on the topic but none seem to work for my problem.

I just got [an answer to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611904/linux-how-to-replace-a-string-of-text-containing-quotes-and-commas-in-a-file/32612011?noredirect=1#comment53087680_32612011) on how to add prefixes to 2 strings of text in a long, single-line .json file.

The command is

```
sed -i 's~"libraries"~"pack/\0"~; s~"objects"~"pack/\0"~' /var/www/html/pack/file.json
```

and it contains single and double quotes, as well as forward and double slashes, making other answers fail.

I've tried

```
ssh ip<<'EOF'
sed -i 's~"libraries"~"pack/\0"~; s~"objects"~"pack/\0"~' /var/www/html/pack/file.json
EOF

ssh ip 'sed -i '"'"'s~"libraries"~"pack/\0"~; s~"objects"~"pack/\0"~'"'"' /var/www/html/pack/file.json'
```

and [everything on this page](http://zaiste.net/2014/08/a_few_ways_to_execute_commands_remotely_using_ssh/), and possibly a couple other things from answers here, with no luck.

The first command, with `EOF`, opens the same screen I would get when simply `ssh ip`-ing; a remote command prompt. The same happens with some other commands from the Zaiste.net page.

Please note that the `sed` command is being run from a script executed in terminal. Thus, multiple line answers are OK.

Also,

```
ssh ip 'sed -i '"'"'s~"libraries"~"pack/\0"~; s~"objects"~"pack/\0"~'"'"' /var/www/html/pack/file.json'
```

returns **EXTRA** quotes around the "objects" and "libraries" strings I am trying to prefix, for example

"minimumVersion":2,"librariesLocation":"pack/**"libraries"**","objectsLocation":"pack/**"objects"**",

If the extra quotes issue from this command can be resolved, that's the solution to my problem.

Comment: Sometimes this is that simple as : `scp script server:script; ssh server 'bash script'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ssh -t -t ip<<'EOF'
sed -i 's~"libraries"~"pack/&"~; s~"objects"~"pack/&"~' /var/www/html/pack/file.json
exit
EOF
```